# Does C have a generic "pointer to a pointer" type?

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

For example, if I wanted to write a "free" that nulled the pointer, I could write something like:

```
void myfree(void **data) {
    free(*data);
    *data = NULL;
}
```

however, when I try to write this, I get a compiler warning (from gcc 4.6.2) saying: `warning: passing argument 1 of ‘myfree’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] ... note: expected ‘void **’ but argument is of type ‘char **‘` (in this case, I am freeing a char array).

It seems that `void*` is special cased to avoid this kind of warning, since `calloc`, `free` etc. don't trigger such warnings, but `void**` is not (given the above).  Is the only solution an explicit cast, or have I misunderstood something?

[I am revisiting some pain points in a recent project, wondering how they could have been handled better, and so am poking at corner cases, hence the C questions today.]

*update* given that `void*` is special cased, I could hack around this using `void*` and casts inside `myfree`, but that would be a somewhat irresponsible solution because everyone and their dog are going to pass a pointer to something that looks like `free`, so I need some kind of compiler warning based on "degree of indirection" for this to be a practical solution.  hence the idea of a generic "pointer to a pointer".

Comment: Just cast to `void**` when passing.

Comment: right, but it's ugly + messy, especially when `free` doesn't need it.  hence wondered if there was anything better.

Comment: As an aside, IMO you should not routinely set pointers to null when you free them. There are situations where you do need to, and there are situations where you can't (for example if the pointer itself is `const`). Other people think it's very important to always set to null, but I think they should instead design their code differently, so that they have fewer dangling pointers in the first place. Most (not all) of the time, you free a pointer just before you free the struct that contains it, or just before the pointer itself goes out of scope. So there's no point nulling it: it's gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, the standard allows different object pointer types to have different representations (even different sizes), although `char*` and `void*` are required have the same representation. But the following is UB:

```
int *ip = 0;
free(*(void**)(&ip));
```

simply because the memory for `ip` need not be the same size as the memory for a `void*`, and even if it is the bit pattern for a null pointer of type `int*` need not be the same as the bit pattern for a null pointer of type `void*`. If they're different, then of course the compiler has to insert code to convert between them whenever you convert an `int*` to `void*` or back.

In practice, implementations don't do that to you (and for example Posix forbids it).

More importantly though, the strict aliasing rules don't allow you to access a `char*` object using an lvalue of type `void*`. So in practice, concerns about pointer representation will not break your code, but the optimizer actually might. Basically, if the function call `myfree((void**)(&p))` gets inlined, then the compiler might see:

```
char *p = <something>;
void **data = (void**)(&p);
free(*data);
*data = NULL;
// code that reads p
```

The optimizer is allowed to note that `*data = NULL` is setting an object of type `void*`, whereas the "code that reads p" is reading an object of type `char*`, which is forbidden from being aliased with that other, `void*` object over there. So it is allowed to reorder the instructions, eliminate `*data = NULL;` entirely, or possibly other things I haven't thought of that will ruin your day, but that would speed the code up if you hadn't broken the rules.

Comment: UB?  what does that mean (sorry)?

Comment: Undefined Behavior. It means that the standard doesn't care what happens. Implementations can do anything they like, and often whatever they do is accidental and hence is unpleasant and/or inconsistent.

Comment: ok, thanks, i am going to need to think.  right now it's not clear to me how some of this is undefined, yet stdlib manages fine with void*.

Comment: You can *convert* any object pointer type to `void*`, but that conversion might (is permitted by the standard to) take time and effort, and involve changing the bit-pattern. Hence you can't (aren't allowed to) just read another pointer type as if it was a `void*`. Similarly, you can convert an `int` to `double`, but you can't just read an `int` as if it were a `double`.

Comment: The reason for the strict aliasing rules is that allowing for potential aliasing genuinely does slow down programs even when no aliasing actually occurs. So rules which allow the compiler to assume that no aliasing occurs, speed up programs. It is a trade-off, though, since sometimes you want to alias different types but the language doesn't let you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the MACRO to do this operation. This will be really great compare to having a function; I hope you know the advantage of using MACRO.

```
#define FREE_IF_NOT_NULL(x) if (x != NULL) { \
                                            free(x); \
                                            x = NULL; \
                                       }
```

Comment: `free()` is null-safe - the `if` is superfluos; an equivalent definition would be `((void)(free(x), x = NULL))`

Comment: I hope you know the disadvantages of using macros.